# Real matrices with $n$ real positive eigenvalues, $A^2=B^2$. Prove that $A=B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ and $B$ be real $n\times n $ matrices such that both of their characteristic polynomials split into linear factors over $\mathbb{R}$ and each eigenvalue is positive . If $A^2=B^2$, then prove that $A=B$.

Comment: Hint: both are diagonalizables

Comment: @vvnitram i dont think so , consider the jordan block example

Comment: Wait... Do you mean distinct n real positive eigenvalues?

Comment: @vvnitram no , i merely mean the (real) characteristic polynomial is split in R

Comment: @hctb then it's false. Take $$\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0}, \quad 0$$

Comment: Are the eigenvalues distinct?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom But for your matrix, not all eigenvalues are positive...

Comment: @hctb oh, are the eigenvalues positive? That should be in the title.

Comment: The question was recently edited to include that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $A$ is a matrix with positive eigenvalues in Jordan form, note that $A$ and $A^2$ will have the same block structure.

Comment: Is there a way without Jordan normal form ?

Comment: i stuck here can you help me ? if diag{J_i(a)2}(2means square)=(A_ij)2(square) , where J_i(a) are the jordan block with diagonal element a,  then (Aij)=diag{Ji}

Answer (score 3):

Look up Theorem 1.29 on *principal square roots* in Nicholas Higham's book
*Functions of Matrices*, SIAM 2008. This theorem says that a square matrix without an eigenvalue $\leq 0$ has exactly one square root such that all its eigenvalue belong to the right half plane.

Comment: @ Edgar M.E. Wermuth . Hi, Edgar, are you still working about the matrix exponential ?